# MonadBaseControl IO ... StateT Implementation

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'am trying to figure out how to implement an instance of [MonadBaseControl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html) for type Foo which is a newtype wrapper around a StateT instance. You would think it would be implemented just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137838/creating-monadbasecontrol-instance-for-newtype) but that does not seem to be the case. I'm assuming the state piece is causing the issue here, so is there a way to drop it?

Code:

```
newtype Foo a = Foo { unFoo :: StateT Int IO a } 
                deriving (Monad, Applicative, Functor, MonadBase IO)

instance MonadBaseControl IO Foo where
   type StM Foo a = a 
   liftBaseWith f = Foo $ liftBaseWith $ \q -> f (q . unFoo)
   restoreM = Foo . restoreM
```

Error:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘(a, Int)’
 ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
 the type signature for restoreM :: StM Foo a -> Foo a
  Expected type: a -> StateT Int IO a  
 Actual type: StM (StateT Int IO) a -> StateT Int IO a
 Relevant bindings include
 restoreM :: StM Foo a -> Foo a
 In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘restoreM’
  In the expression: Foo . restoreM
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid `UndecidableInstances`, the linked answer expanded a type family that, for human readability, it really shouldn't have. Namely, he writes

```
instance MonadBaseControl IO Foo where
    type StM Foo a = a
```

when instead one might consider writing

```
instance MonadBaseControl IO Foo where
    type StM Foo a = StM (ReaderT Int IO) a
```

to make it more clear how to choose the correct right-hand side for a given newtype wrapping. With the analogous change (and `UndecidableInstances`), your code works fine. If you want to avoid `UndecidableInstances`, you can do the same expansion done in the linked answer; an example of asking ghci what the expansion should be looks like this:

```
> :kind! forall a. StM (StateT Int IO) a
forall a. StM (StateT Int IO) a :: *
= (a, Int)
```

So for the `StateT` version of `Foo` we could also write:

```
instance MonadBaseControl IO Foo where
    type StM Foo a = (a, Int)
```

Comment: Nice, this worked. Thanks! Out of curiosity how would I write the kinds version so that I don't need the "UndecidableInstances"?

Comment: @Josh What do you mean by "the kinds version"?

Comment: Woops sorry, guess I worded that wrong? Essentially how do I use the "forall a. StM (StateT Int IO) a" to avoid the "UndecidableInstances".

Comment: @Josh Using the code that immediately follows that in my answer...?

Comment: yes. I'm not familiar with how to use the forall syntax.

Comment: @Josh I'm really not sure what you're asking. My answer suggests two potential instance declarations for your `Foo`; one uses associated type `type StM Foo a = StM ({- unwrapping of Foo -}StateT Int IO) a` and requires `UndecidableInstances`, while the other uses associated type `type StM Foo a = {- expanded unwrapping of Foo -} (a, Int)` and doesn't. How can I be more explicit about the syntax to use for these than giving the actual syntax to use?